# Firebase Help Organizing Database (Simple Answer?)

Tags: json, database, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently developing an app that requires me to store a database like so:

(I will do three districts and two schools for the sake of space)

```
Districts

-District 1
--School 1
---Period 1
----End Time
---Period 2
----End Time
--School 2
---Period 1
----End Time
---Period 2
----End Time

-District 2
--School 1
---Period 1
----End Time
---Period 2
----End Time
--School 2
---Period 1
----End Time
---Period 2
----End Time

-District 3
--School 1
---Period 1
----End Time
---Period 2
----End Time
--School 2
---Period 1
----End Time
---Period 2
----End Time
```

The issue is I want to have each District to hold a value (name), and each school to hold a value (name), as well as the period name and the end time to hold values. Though Firebase or JSON in general, won't let me derive more objects off of something that has a value (such as a district).

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i were you, i would structure the database like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Schools
   |      |
   |      --- schoolId1
   |              |
   |              --- schoolName: School Name 1
   |              |
   |              --- Period1: EndTime
   |              |
   |              --- Period2: EndTime
   |              |
   |              --- Districts
   |                     |
   |                     --- District1: true
   |                     |
   |                     --- District2: true
   |
   --- Districts
          |
          --- DistrictId1
                  |
                  --- districtsName: Districts Name 1
                  |
                  --- Schools
                         |
                         --- School1: true
                         |
                         --- School2: true
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, You are definitely on to something, though each period needs to hold a plethora of data, such as end time, period name (ex "4th Period & A Lunch"), and other small needed values such as a boolean to send a notification or not a few minutes before the period ends. I should have made this clear I needed to hold many more values, sorry, and again, thank you.

Comment: There is no problem. You can add those value too. This type of structure can hold many more. I just gave you an example how to restructure your database in a more efficient way.